# Big Query job fails with "Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered."

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a job that is failing with the error

> Line:14222274 / Field:1, Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered. Rest of file not processed.

The data is compressed and I have verified that no ASCII 0 character exists in the file. There are only 14222273 lines in the file, so the line number that is printed in the error message is one line past the end of the file. I have other chunks from the same data set which have uploaded successfully, so I suspect that this is either a BQ bug, or the error message is not indicative of the underlying issue. Any help solving this problem would be appreciated. Thanks.

```python
>>> data = open("data.csv").read()
>>> chr(0) in data
False
>>> data[-1]
'\n'
```

Comment: Hi John: can you confirm that the uncompressed file does not end with a trailing '\0' character?

Comment: @MichaelManoochehri
The last byte in the file is a newline.  
`>>> chr(0) in open("data.csv").read()
False`

Comment: It's almost impossible to debug this without the actual data. Could you take the original problem file, uncompress is, split it into 2 files, re-gzip and re-ingest  into BigQuery? Alternatively, could you create a new file with just the last 2 lines of the original file, try to re-ingest, and let us know if you get the same error?

Comment: @MichaelManoochehri I tested both scenarios. I created 3 files, one with just the last 2 lines, one with the first half, and one with the second half. I gzipped and uploaded all 3 and they all completed successfully.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problems, trying to load in BigQuery a compressed file (saved it in Google Cloud Storage). These are the logs:

```
File: 0 / Offset:4563403089 / Line:328480 / Field:21: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered: field starts with:  (error code: invalid)
File: 0 / Offset:4563403089 / Line:328485 / Field:21: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered: field starts with:  (error code: invalid)
File: 0 / Offset:4563403089 / Line:328490 / Field:21: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered: field starts with:  (error code: invalid)
File: 0 / Offset:4563403089 / Line:328511 / Field:21: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered: field starts with:  (error code: invalid)
File: 0 / Offset:4563403089 / Line:328517 / Field:21: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered: field starts with:  (error code: invalid)
```

For resolve the problem what I've done is remove the ASCII 0 characters from the compressed file. To do it, I executed the following commnad from an instance of Compute Engine with the sdk installed:

```
gsutil cp gs://bucket_987234/compress_file.gz - | gunzip | tr -d '\000' | gsutil cp - gs://bucket_987234/uncompress_and_clean_file
```

By using pipelines, I avoid having to have all storage on the hard disk (1G compress + 52G uncompress). The first program gets the compressed file from Storage, the second decompresses it, the thrid removes the ASCII 0 characters and the fourth program updaloads the result to Storage.

I don't compress the result when I upload again to Storage, because for BigQuery is faster load a uncompressed file. After that I can load on BigQuery the data without problems.

Comment: My question is that if I want to use python to excute the gsutil shell, I need to concatenate a string . It is hard to generate a string '\000' . I posted a question in here. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69231318/how-to-generate-the-string-x000-in-python.     would you help me take a look?

Answer (score 1):

When you compress what utility did you use?.

I saw this issue when i compressed my csv file in ZIP format ( in windows) . Google BigQuery seems to accept only gzip format.

Make sure to compress your CSV using gzip. If you are in windows [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) is a great utility which allows you to compress in gzip.

In Unix gzip is standard.

Comment: I'm using gzip 1.3.12 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Have you also checked the character encoding. The file is supposed to be UTF-8 format. It also supports one other encoding. Character Encodings
By default, the BigQuery service expects all source data to be UTF-8 encoded. Optionally, if you have data encoded in ISO-8859-1 format, you should explicitly specify the encoding when you import your data so that BigQuery can properly convert your data to UTF-8 during the import process. Currently, it is only possible to import data that is ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8 encoded. Keep in mind the following when you specify the character encoding of your data:

Answer (score -1):

> **Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered. Rest of file not processed.**

Clearly states you have a UTF-16 character there which cannot be decoded. BigQuery service only supports UTF-8 and latin1 text encodings. So, the file is supposed to be UTF-8 encoded.

> There are only 14222273 lines in the file, so the line number that is
>   printed in the error message is one line past the end of the file.

Probably you have a UTF-16 encoded tab character at the end of the file, which cannot be decoded.

---

**Solution**: Use the `-a` or `--ascii` flag with `gzip` command. It'll be decoded ok by `bigquery`.