# Loading into BigQuery: Offset:805306369 / Line:1 / Field:1, Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to load a .csv file into Google BigQuery, but I keep running into this error: "Offset:805306369 / Line:1 / Field:1, Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered. Rest of file not processed."  ASCII 0 means it is getting a null.  I have looked at the file and I have values in the file, so I don't know if this is something that is a bug, or if I am trying to load it incorrectly.  I would appreciate some help, let me know if you guys need any other information.

Comment: have you tried splitting the file in 2?  (to find out if the weird character is in the first half or the second half of the file)

Comment: Ok, so I tried splitting it up and I am getting the same thing with all of my files, I think I'm going to try to make a new file to upload because I am starting to think that the problem is the file I have and not BQ.

Comment: Reloading the table fixed this.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Big Query job fails with "Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021610/big-query-job-fails-with-bad-character-ascii-0-encountered)

Comment: @KevinJ.Bird what do you mean by *Reloading*? I have a csv file like you had and I am getting the same error.