# How to generate the string 'x000' in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to run the below command in python. I need to print the '\0000'. I try different ways to print it. I got '\x00' or '\000'. How do generate the string '\000' in python? thank you so much.

```
gsutil cp xxxxx.csv - | tr -d '\000' | gsutil cp - xxxxx.csv
```

```
>>> remove_string='''\000'''

>>> remove_string

'\x00'


>>> remove_string='\\000'
>>> remove_string
'\\000'
>>> remove_string=r'\\000'

>>> remove_string
'\\\\000'
>>> remove_string=r'\000'
>>> remove_string
'\\000'
```

Comment: backslash (\\) has special meaning in strings, so it needs to be escaped - `'\\000'` or `r'\000'`

Comment: i tried but i still cannot get \000

Comment: When you type an expression in the Python interactive mode, you're shown the `repr()` of the value, not its `str()`.  `'\\000'` *is* the `repr()` of your desired string.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `\000` usually means a null byte - your code looks like it’s just trying to delete null bytes from an input. In that case, `\x00` or `\0` or `\000` will all be equivalent. Maybe try providing some more context for how you intend to use this string.

Comment: After `remove_string='\\000'` try `print(remove_string)`. Then you get the contained string which is the 4 characters you want. The shell prints `repr(remove_string)` which adds quotes and escapes to make the string look like a python literal.

Comment: If you’re literally trying to get that string into a command for e.g. subprocess, then you can just use doubled backslashes, i.e. `\\000`.

Comment: Another way of checking strings is `print(list(remove_string))`. Each item in the list is 1 character, but some of them may be represented by multi-character literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string literal is the text you type into a program that python compiles into a `str` object. Python treats the backslash character `\` specially - it allows you to enter characters that are not on the keyboard. But sometimes you need the backslash so it can be unescaped with `\\`. When displaying strings, python has both `repr` and `str` versions of the string. `repr` gives you the literal sting version, while `str` gives you the real string. Its a bit confusing that "literal" is literally *not* the string. If you escape the string and print it, you'll see the real characters.

```
>>> remove_string = '\\000'
>>> remove_string
'\\000'
>>> print(remove_string)
\000
```

You also used raw strings. Prepending with "r" tells python to stop using the backslash as a special string in a string literal. However, if you take the repr of that string later, you'll still get the special string literal represenation. No, problem though, because the string is correct.

```
>>> remove_string = r'\000'
>>> remove_string
'\\000'
>>> print(remove_string)
\000
```